# Access Java Enum fields in javascript

Tags: javascript, java, spring, enums

I'm trying to access the `facility` String of this enum in java script

```
public enum FacilityEnum {

    CAR_VALET("carValet"),
    INDOOR("indoorPark"),
    DISABLED_ACCESS("disabledAccess"),
    EV_CHARGE("evCharge"),

    private String facility;

    private FacilityEnum(String facility) {
        this.facility = facility;
    }

    public String getFacility() {
        return facility;
    }

    public void setFacility(String facility) {
        this.facility = facility;
    }



}
```

This enum is used in a Facility.class

```
@Entity
public class Facility {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long facilityId;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private FacilityEnum service;


    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "facilities")
    @JsonBackReference("parks-facilities-services")
    private Set<Park> parks;
    }


    public FacilityEnum getService() {
        return service;
    }

    public void setService(FacilityEnum service) {
        this.service = service;
    }
```

which has a ManyToMany relation with Park.class.

The problem comes when i need to use the `facility` String in javascript

This the javascript interested part, i'm using Spring + Thymleaf

```
var parcheggi = JSON.parse([[${parks}]]); //my list of Parks
parcheggi.forEach(function (arrayItem) { //it's ok

            var parcheggio = arrayItem;
            var services = parcheggio.facilities; //it's ok, i get Facility objects
            var servicesDiv = '<div>';
            services.forEach(function (service){
                var s = service; //the single Facility

                servicesDiv += '<img src="/images/park_icons/facilities/' + s.service + '.png" />'
            });
            servicesDiv += '</div>';

 //rest of the code...
```

In this case `s.service` is the rough Enum (CAR_VALET, INDOOR...) if i try `s.service.facility` I get undefined.. I need to have carValet, indoor, disabledAccess and so on...

Comment: Are you using jackson for json serialization?

Comment: Yes i do, the serialization works, i'm getting all' the services

Comment: Can you please show the getter and setter of your `facility`enum?

Comment: Sure, i've added them in Facility.class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do what you want is to configure object mapper to serialize enums using toString method. You would add the following to the object mapper configuration:

```
 objectMapper.enable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_ENUMS_USING_TO_STRING);
```

(Note that previous Jackson versions have equivalent to this property but it's different).

Then just add toString to your enum:

```
@Override
public String toString ()
{
    return facility;
}
```

Comment: Even though this works, it is not a great idea to depend on toString for your business logic. toString is intended to provide a human-readable representation of an object for logging purposes. The problem is that Java enums are flattened to a single string when represented as JSON. I suggest creating a separate Data Transfer Object (DTO) containing all the data needed by your views, including a String facility, which you populate server side with the correct values.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting `undefined` because your Enum can't be deserialized in JSON, you have two options here:

- Either change the Implementation of your Enum, so it contains only the `String`constants and it will be correctly mapped by Jackson.

Your code would be:

```
public enum FacilityEnum {
    CAR_VALET,
    INDOOR,
    DISABLED_ACCESS,
    EV_CHARGE;
}
```

- Or you should override the `toString()` method in your Enum so it can
  be deserialized and returned as a `String`.

Your code would be:

```
public enum FacilityEnum {

  CAR_VALET("carValet"),
    INDOOR("indoorPark"),
    DISABLED_ACCESS("disabledAccess"),
    EV_CHARGE("evCharge"),

    private String facility;

  private FacilityEnum(String facility) {
    this.facility = facility;
  }

  public String getFacility() {
    return facility;
  }

  public void setFacility(String facility) {
    this.facility = facility;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return facility;
  }

}
```

Comment: thanks, it'j just the solution i made thanks to @xsx4u